# Angular dynamic ng-src function results in "10 $digest() iterations reached" error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I recently inherited an asp.net project that uses Angular, which is very new to me, so I apologize in advance for any rudimentary questions or assumptions.

The markup / js below results in an endless number of the following error:

> 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Angular version 1.2.27

I have the following markup (showing only relevant parts for brevity).

```
<div id="RecentContentGrid" ng-controller="RecentContentCtrl" ng-cloak>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="item.contentType.toLowerCase() && getItemClass(item)" ng-switch on="item.contentType">
        <a href="{{item.url}}" class="content clearfix" title="{{item.displayName}}" ng-switch-default>                                     
           <img ng-src="{{getThumbUrlBySize(item, 320)}}?mh=320" />
        </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My issue is with the **"ng-src="{{getThumbUrlBySize(item, 320)}}"** part.  This calls a method in the controller, which in turn calls a web service to get a image based on the specified height:

```
$scope.getThumbUrlBySize = function(item, size){
        VideoThumbnail.query({ embedCode : item.embedCode, maxHeight: size }, function (data) {
                return data.Content;
            });            
    }
```

The controller also has the following watch methods:

```
// Watch Methods
    $scope.$watch('params.category', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (typeof(newVal) == 'string') {
            $scope.params.perPage = $scope.total_items;
        }

        $scope.items = [];
    });

    $scope.$watchCollection('params', function () {
        var items = [];

        $q.all(_.compact([fetchArticles(), fetchVideos()])).then(function (data) {
            items = _.flatten(data);

            if (items.length == $scope.total_items) {
                items = $filter('orderBy')(items, 'CreatedAt').reverse();

                if (typeof(ad_content) != 'undefined' && ad_content.length > 0 && $scope.ads_served == false) {
                    items = injectAds(items);
                }

                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    items[i].cssClass = "block-" + (i + 1);
                }

                // Append scope items
                $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(items);
            }
            else {
                $scope.messages.push("No more items");
            }
        });
    });
```

My question is how do I get a dynamic image url based on the specific item property and the passed in value for the size?  As I mentioned, Angular is very new to me, so I'd appreciate specific details.

Oh, and I should that that the controller is used for many parts of the site, and that's why the size is passed in on the specific module, rather than at the scope level.  The maxHeight variable will change based on where this module is used.

Thank you very much.

Comment: your `$scope.getThumbUrlBySize` return nothing. Can you provide [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It'd be much better if you didn't bind to a function result in the view as the function will be executed with every digest. Instead, run the function in the controller to fill a scope property and then bind to that property instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code I can see:

- the function `getThumbUrlBySize` does not return anything. Therefore the markup `{{getThumbUrlBySize(item, 320)}}?mh=320` fails to interpolate, leaving `img` tags with empty `src` attribute.
- `VideoThumbnail.query` seems to be asynchronous. Even if it returned a Promise object, the markup wouldn't be interpolated with the resolved value.
- The `VideoThumbnail.query`'s callback does not actually do anything with the value it's passed (assuming that the method itself doesn't do anything with the value returned from its callback - which is unlikely)

None of these problems seems to cause an infinite $digest loop (from the code you've posted I'd suspect the `injectAds` function), however they prevent your code from working properly ;)

The easiest way I can imagine right now is to replace the `for` loop in `$watchCollection` handler with the following:

```
angular.forEach(items, function(item, i) {
    item.cssClass = "block-" + (i + 1); // this comes from the original for loop
    VideoThumbnail.query({ embedCode : item.embedCode, maxHeight: 320 }, function (data) {
        item.thumbnail = data.Content + "?mh=320";
        /* 
           VideoThumbnail.query accepts a callback instead of returning a Promise, 
           so we have to tell AngularJS to "refresh" when the asynchronous
           job is done:
        */
        $scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

and the `img` markup:

```
<img ng-src="{{item.thumbnail}}" />
```

I wouldn't call this solution perfect, but it should work :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and the suggested resolution.  Your solution did work, but did not allow me to pass in the max height dynamically to the controller. However, it made me realize the inefficiency in doing it that way. I went back and included the thumbUrl in the original server side code, and created an angular controller parameter to pass in the required height.  This way, everything is returned in the original collection.query rather than a manipulation of the data after the fact.  Thank you.